# Scala : how to convert integer to time stamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am facing an issue when i am trying to find the number of months between two dates using 'months_between'function. when my input date format is 'dd/mm/yyyy' or any other date format then the function is returning the correct output. however when i am passing the input date format as yyyymmdd then i am getting the below error.

Code:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMdd").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("MyFile.csv")
 val filteredMemberDF = df.withColumn("monthsBetween", functions.months_between(col("toDate"), col("fromDT")))
```

error:

> cannot resolve 'months_between(`toDate`, `fromDT`)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires timestamp type,
>        however, '`toDate`' is of int type. argument 2 requires timestamp type, however, '`fromDT`' is of int type.;

When my input is as below,

```
id   fromDT     toDate
11   16/06/2008  16/08/2008
12   13/07/2008  13/10/2008
```

getting expected output,

```
id   fromDT     toDate     monthsBetween
11   16/6/2008  16/8/2008      2
12   13/7/2008  13/10/2008     3
```

when i am passing the below data, facing the above said error.

```
id   fromDT     toDate  
11   20150930  20150930  
12   20150930  20150930
```

Comment: Your data has other format that this put in Spark configuraiton

Comment: The problem is that Spark is thinking that things like `20150930` are mean to be numbers and not date. So it reading them as Int int the DF.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to use `to_date` function to convert those numbers to DateTimes.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.read
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMdd")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("MyFile.csv")

val dfWithDates = df
  .withColumn("toDateReal", to_date(concat(col("toDate")), "yyyyMMdd"))
  .withColumn("fromDateReal", to_date(concat(col("fromDT")), "yyyyMMdd"))

val filteredMemberDF = dfWithDates
  .withColumn("monthsBetween", months_between(col("toDateReal"), col("fromDateReal")))
```